# How to specify hierarchical columns in Pandas merge?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, hierarchical-data

After a serious misconception of how `on` works in `join` (spoiler: very different from `on` in `merge`), this is my example code.

```
import pandas as pd

index1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["variables"], ["number", "fruit"]])
df1 = pd.DataFrame([["one", "apple"], ["two", "banana"]], columns=index1)

index2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["variables"], ["fruit", "color"]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([["banana", "yellow"]], columns=index2)

print(df1.merge(df2, on="fruit", how="left"))
```

I get a `KeyError`. How do I correctly reference `variables.fruit` here?

To understand what I am after, consider the same problem without a multi index:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([["one", "apple"], ["two", "banana"]], columns=["number", "fruit"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([["banana", "yellow"]], columns=["fruit", "color"])

# this is obviously incorrect as it uses indexes on `df1` as well as `df2`:
print(df1.join(df2, rsuffix="_"))

# this is *also* incorrect, although I initially thought it should work, but it uses the index on `df2`:
print(df1.join(df2, on="fruit", rsuffix="_"))

# this is correct:
print(df1.merge(df2, on="fruit", how="left"))
```

The expected and wanted result is this:

```
  number   fruit   color
0    one   apple     NaN
1    two  banana  yellow
```

How do I get the same when `fruit` is part of a multi index?

Comment: I am not sure why you would expect the NaN to be in the top row.  The index of the `df2` only has the first element at `0`.

Comment: @BillHuang I want to join the two data frames not on the two indexes, but on a non-index column in *both* data frames. Apparently, `join` does not do that - it always uses the *index* in the right data frame.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So you'd like to join column-wise instead of row-wise, as if the indexes were built on columns, right?

Comment: @BillHuang I completely revised the question, I hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you are trying to accomplish now, and I don't think `join` is going to get you there.  Both `DataFrame.join` and `DataFrame.merge` make a call to `pandas.core.reshape.merge.merge`, but using `DataFrame.merge` gives you more control over what defaults are applied.

In your case, you can use reference the columns to join on via a list of tuples, where the elements of the tuple are the levels of the multi-indexed columns.  I.e. to use the `variables / fruit` column, you can pass `[('variables', 'fruit')]`.

Using tuples is how you index into multi-index columns (and row indices).  You need to wrap it in a list because merge operations can be performed using multiple columns, or multiple multi-indexed columns, like a JOIN statement in SQL.  Passing a single string is just a convenience case that gets wrapped in a list for you.

Since you are only joining on 1 column, it is a list of a single tuple.

```
import pandas as pd

index1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["variables"], ["number", "fruit"]])
df1 = pd.DataFrame([["one", "apple"], ["two", "banana"]], columns=index1)

index2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["variables"], ["fruit", "color"]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([["banana", "yellow"]], columns=index2)

df1.merge(df2, how='left', on=[('variables', 'fruit')])
# returns:
  variables
     number   fruit   color
0       one   apple     NaN
1       two  banana  yellow
```

Comment: Ok, I have updated my answer in response to the update in the question.

Comment: "a list of a single tuple" - *obviously*. Thank you!